# How to parse Aria-Label from a div tag attribute?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I am using JSoup to parse some HTMLL information, and I would like to parse the aria label value of a specific div attribute. The line I am trying to parse is the following:

```
<div class="tiny-star star-rating-non-editable-container" aria-label=" Rated   5 stars out of five stars ">
```

I have used the following:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements stars= document.select("div.tiny-star star-rating-non-editable-container[aria-label]");
String value = stars.text();
System.out.println("The rating is " + value);
```

However, the String value, returns blank. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That selector expression won't give you what you expect.  It's treated as a two-part selector

- `div.tiny-star` - find a `div` element with class `tiny-star`
- `star-rating-non-editable-container[aria-label]` - then look for a descendant `star-rating-non-editable-container` element which has an `aria-label` attribute

Try something more like

```
Element divWithStars = document.select(
   "div.tiny-star.star-rating-non-editable-container[aria-label]");
String ariaLabel = divWithStars.attr("aria-label");
```

Note the dot rather than space between `tiny-star` and `star-rating-...`, and also the fact that `select` returns the *element that hosts the aria-label attribute*, not the attribute itself - you have to use `attr` to extract the attribute value.